# How write BeanShellPostProcessor script for comparing two values

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I want compare two values and pick which one is equal to second variable.
I have written code like below in BeanShellPostProcessor

```
HitID = vars.get("AddPrpc139");
b=139
if(HitID.equals(b))
{
log.info("......value=");
}else
{
    log.info("......value=");
}
```

But i am getting below error

2018-11-27 14:48:53,504 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: `` HitID = vars.get("AddPrpc139"); b=139 if(HitID.equals(b)) { log.info("......val . . . '' Encountered "if" at line 4, column 1.

2018-11-27 14:48:53,504 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: `` HitID = vars.get("AddPrpc139"); b=139 if(HitID.equals(b)) { log.info("......val . . . '' Encountered "if" at line 4, column 1.

Answer (score 0):

Java/Beanshell expect `;` at end of the line. Also `b` can be inlined

```
 HitID = vars.get("AddPrpc139");
 if("139".equals(HitIDb))
 {
```

Also consider moving to JSR223 PostProcessor

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to follow [Java syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_syntax.asp) rules, to wit you need to add a semicolon after `b=139` line.
2. You should also surround this `139` with quotation marks otherwise JMeter will be comparing a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) with an [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and you will always get into `else` branch even if the values will be the same

Amended code:

```
HitID = vars.get("AddPrpc139");
b = "139";
if (HitID.equals(b)) {
    log.info("Values are equal, expected: " + b + ", got: " + HitID);
} else {
    log.info("Values are NOT equal, expected: " + b + ", got: " + HitID);
}'
```

Demo:

[image]

---

Be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should be using JSR223 PostProcessor with Groovy language starting from JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). Groovy is more modern language, it is compatible with latest Java features and it has much better performance. Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.

Comment: Hi HDmitri T,  the above code is working fine, but i need to use the expected value in my script. how can i pick the value and substitute in my script.

Comment: You can use "Parameters" section to pass the value and amend the line `b = "139";` to look like `b = Parameters`